# Custom Install.php template

Tags: theming, installation, commerce, distributions

In the process of developing a distribution, I'm stuck with the task to customize the install.php page. Can't find a way to change the tpl/layout of the installation process or which preprocess function to use.

I'd like to do the same as Commerce Kickstart did, in a certain way.

Any ideas how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's the trick that Kickstart uses (from commerce_kickstart.install).
The actual styling is in the [Shiny](http://drupal.org/project/shiny) admin theme.

```
/**
 * Implements hook_install_tasks_alter().
 */
function commerce_kickstart_install_tasks_alter(&$tasks, $install_state) {
  _commerce_kickstart_set_theme('shiny');
}

/**
 * Force-set a theme at any point during the execution of the request.
 *
 * Drupal doesn't give us the option to set the theme during the installation
 * process and forces enable the maintenance theme too early in the request
 * for us to modify it in a clean way.
 */
function _commerce_kickstart_set_theme($target_theme) {
  if ($GLOBALS['theme'] != $target_theme) {
    unset($GLOBALS['theme']);

    drupal_static_reset();
    $GLOBALS['conf']['maintenance_theme'] = $target_theme;
    _drupal_maintenance_theme();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you reviewed the code used in the [Commerce Kickstart](http://drupalcode.org/project/commerce_kickstart.git) distribution? They don't really change the "layout".  What they did was they modified the glbal variable in kickstart that stores the theme used:

```
if ($GLOBALS['theme'] != $target_theme) {
    unset($GLOBALS['theme']);

    drupal_static_reset();
    $GLOBALS['conf']['maintenance_theme'] = $target_theme;
    _drupal_maintenance_theme();
  }
```